# SimpleITK: registration with composite transform

Tags: image-processing, simpleitk, image-registration

I'm trying to use a composite transform (TranslationTransform + ScaleTransform) for registration. The concept is to first register with Translation, then do [Translation, Scale] with the initial transform of the translation given by the solution of the initial registration. If you try and do this with a composite transform, only the last transform added will get modified though, and all the higher order transform types include rotation - priors let me know that the rotation is well determined and shouldnt be modified as a degree of freedom. I can think of two ways of solving this:

1. Come up with a way of allowing registration on a composite transform which allows for parameters from both transform to be modified - maybe using the base Transform class?
2. Come up with a way of holding certain parameters constant in a higher order transform during registration.
   **EDIT** I think that the SetOptimizerWeights function can be used to do this way of solving the problem. **EDIT** You aren't allowed to SetOptimizerWeights for the L-BFGS type optimizers, meaning there is no easy way to mask dimensions. As these proved to be much much more robust across datasets, in the end I may just allow for registration to occur across the higher order space.

I dont know how to do either of these things and cant find any (good) documentation on either... any help very appreciated!!

Answer (score 3):

Your proposed solution 2 is the straightforward approach to doing what you want:

1. Use an `AffineTransform(3)`.
2. The parameters of the affine transform `GetParameters()` are in row major order.
3. For first registration, only translation, `SetOptimizerWeights([0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1])` only translation portion is active.
4. For the second registration, only scaling, `SetOptimizerWeights([1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0])` only scale portion is active.

An aside, yes, this specific feature is not well documented, but the toolkit has extensive documentation, both on [read-the-docs](https://simpleitk.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) and on the toolkit's [juypter notebook repository](https://github.com/InsightSoftwareConsortium/SimpleITK-Notebooks/).

Finally, the main location for Q&A is on the [itk discourse forum](https://discourse.itk.org/).